# How to include regular expression in logstash file input path

Tags: regex, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I am using logstash to convert tomcat access logs into json format. The access log names are in below format

```
abcd_access_log.2016-03-15.log
efgh_access_log.2016-02-16.log
```

The input filter is:

```
input { 
    file {
        path => "C:\tools\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\logs\*_access_log.*.log"
        start_position => beginning
    } 
}
```

It is not showing logs with the regex used. What regex should I use here to select only these files?

Comment: In logstash 2.3 I found that Windows paths must use a forward slash like in Linux. Maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple and fast way**

If your `log` file is always after `logs\`, you can use the following regex:

```
logs\\(.*?\.log)
```

Capture everything `.*?` followed by `logs\` (please note double `\\` in the regex). Also your file ends with `.log`, so dont forget to escape the dot with `\.log`.

Detailed description is at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sH0fL3/1).

---

**Bullet-proof and slower way**

In case there is missing the key characters `logs\`, you can use the following regex, that captures the last part of the path, using the negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
\\((?:.(?!\\))+\.log)
```

Here is the detailed description again: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sH0fL3/2)